# Keytool Private Key Missing Password

Tags: java, android, google-play, code-signing, keytool

An Android app I am managing was published on Android in 2012 signed with a private key that has no password. Now I am trying to publish an updated version, but I am not able to use the same release keystore to sign via Eclipse, which insists a password is required.

I've tried exporting and reimporting into a new keystore, but the process failed halfway as it insists on entering an existing password for the key, which is non-existent.

I've also tried exporting the certificates out and reimporting into a new keystore, which works, but the private key cannot be successfully transferred.

I am stuck now on how to sign the updated app with the existing key which has no password. I've tried all sorts of keytool commands to change passwords but it did not work.

Comment: I assume you have tried using the keystore password for both the keystore and the key itself?

Comment: Actually the keystore and key both do not have any password set... Keytool seems to allow empty password for keystore on command line, but not for the key though.